# Grails Quartz job retrieves old data from MySQL

Tags: mysql, hibernate, grails, grails-orm, quartz-scheduler

I have a single threaded Quartz job that is kicked off after changing a record's 'status' column. The job is passed the primary id for the record which it then looks up. For some strange reason the quartz job sees the original status value.

The job has logic to retry the lookup every second up to a minute. At first I thought that hibernate might be returning the old object so I added a `session.clear()` but that made no difference. I then added a `jdbcTemplate.queryForMap` to pull in the data bypassing hibernate but that too sees the old data.

While the Quartz job is logging the old value, I see the new value in a show view and in a sql query that I manually invoke against the database. I even checked the version property and see that it has changed but the Quartz job has the old value.

Is there any reason why the Quartz job would not recognize the change?

The strange thing is that this logic works perfectly fine on some servers, others it consistently fails and others where it fails periodically.

The environments consist of:

- Grails 1.3.7
- MySQL
- Linux
- Tomcat

Comment: After saving the data make sure you are flushing and if you are using services set the transactional to false, see if that helps.

Comment: I am flushing the the save. The service should be transactional since the method is performing a number of updates. 

I think I narrowed this issue down to something with mySQL. After turning on mysql logging, I see that before the first transaction is completed, that the 2nd connect (for the Quartz job) is initiated and invokes the query that is getting the old data. The first connection then issues the commit and close. Subsequent queries on the 2nd connection still sees the earlier version of the data. It does not recognize the commit.

Comment: Have you tried to wrap them in a withNewSession see if that helps. I had similar problem but I could make the service non-transaction. My guess is the hibernate sessions are different.

Comment: The two processes run in separate threads therefore do not share Hibernate sessions. Further more I used direct JDBC queries in the Quartz job to avoid Hibernate. Therefore I conclude that the problem perhaps lies in the DB.  
I've updated the mysql connector to the latest version but that made no difference. I'm in the process of upgrading MySQL from 5.1 to 5.6 to see if that makes any difference. Interestingly I have one environment using mySQL 5.1.52 that consistently fails and two environments using 5.0.51a of which only one fails occasionally.

Comment: Are you committing the save to the database?

Comment: Yes - the change is committed to the database. I actually see the UPDATE, COMMIT and CLOSE of the first transaction and connection and see the other SELECT statements occurring in the MySQL log file. Other queries of the same record that start after the commit see the change even while the second (quartz job) connection still sees the original value.

Comment: I have ruled out query caching being done by MySQL with configuration of my.cnf (query_cache_size=0) as well as adding SQL_NO_CACHE to the SQL statement that is looking up the record in the 2nd connection. It appears that MySQL is returning the value of the record based on the value of the first query that occurred before the record was updated.

Comment: This problem was eventually resolved. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16018702/mysql-second-connection-does-not-see-committed-change-from-first-connection for the details.