# MySQL second connection does not see committed change from first connection

Tags: mysql, concurrency, transactions, commit

I have a problem with a Grails based application that is connected to MySQL where there is a process that updates a record as part of a larger transaction. This process also kicks off a 2nd thread via a Quartz job that will perform some additional changes. The Quartz job typically starts before the first thread commits the transaction therefore the job loops up to one minute checking for the record to change to the expected state. Oddly it works consistently in some environments, fails consistently in one and infrequently in yet another.

My question has to do with how MySQL recognizes transaction commits between two concurrent connections. One would expect that when connection A performs the commit, that subsequent queries from connection B would recognize the committed change. In my case connection B will have made the same query one or more times before connection A has made the commit. It appears that mySQL is caching the query results for the connection. Oddly enough, while connection B is repeatedly querying and getting the old value, I can issue the same query via the mysql client and see the new value. Does anyone aware of a caching issue or concurrency issues?

For the above observation I have the MySQL log enabled in order to see the individual update, commits and queries occurring.

The various environments are using different versions of MySQL as shown below. I'm in the process of upgrading my environments to the latest MySQL to see if that resolves it.

5.0.51a - two environments that have been very stable with infrequent occurrences however one environment started having increased occurrences over the weekend with moderate traffic.

5.1.55 - one environment consistently fails

Thanks,

John

Comment: I thought that it might be the MySQL query cache so I changed query_cache_size=0 and restarted the database but there was no change in the odd behavior.

Comment: To further rule out query caching, I added SQL_NO_CACHE to the select statement that is attempting to lookup the record from the 2nd connection. This two does not solve the issue. The SQL looks like this - SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE * FROM my_table;

Comment: what is your level of transaction isolation? Are the queries from A and B done in transactions?

Comment: forget that: 1. try instead to open a mysql console and check the if the updates are visible. 2. check whether your grails configuration has query cache enabled. maybe [that](http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Turning-OFF-query-cache-in-grails-td4529815.html) could help.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  What I have is:  1. Yes - I have opened a mysql console and see the change from update all the while the Quartz job iterates and reissues the SQL query to the DB. The job polls the DB every 500ms for 1 minute before giving up. 2. Grails does not have L2 caching configured. I also am using a straight JDBC connection bypassing Hibernate to get the record and include "SQL_NO_CACHE" in the SELECT statement so MySQL should not be caching either. Still baffled.

Comment: Ok, let's unforget my initial comment then: what is the transaction isolation level set for your queries (mysql default should be repeatable read)? do you have autocommit enabled (mysql default should be yes)?

Comment: Recall thar if you have 2 transactions running, in default mode, any read will be consistent with the previous reads and write done within the same transaction - that's isolation. If you are in the lowest isolation level, any update to the db from outside the transaction will be visible, which is basically the same as no isolation. If you are not in a transaction, the effect of a transaction will only be visible once that transaction has been commited.

Comment: Remember that without autocommit, any query after a `COMMIT`, will start a new transaction, and any subsequent query will remain in that transaction, until you emit  `COMMIT` or `ROLLBACK`, at which point other transactions result become visible.

Comment: didierc - thanks for your comments. The transaction isolation was in fact the issue. I wasn't able to neatly manage the transaction within execution of the thread after making several various attempts. Eventually I settled with rescheduling the Quartz job to rerun in 100ms which was long enough for the first thread to commit.

Comment: One of my attempts to control the transaction was to move the Job method to a Service class that was marked as transactional=false and then I managed the transaction within the method. This still didn't work. Apparently the transaction is created before the service method is invoked. I'll explore this under a different post.